How do I print multiple tickets on one sheet?
I am trying to print tickets for a concert.
At the moment I can print each ticket on a separate sheet of paper. But I would like to be able to print each ticket, with a small gap after each one, on as fewer pages as possible.
Here is the code I have:
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $pdf->AddPage();

        // background
        $pdf->SetAlpha($alpha);
        $pdf->Image('../img/banners/'.$row['banner'], 10, 10, 0, 107);
        // draw border around image
        $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
        $pdf->Cell(0,107,'',1,1, 'C');

        // logo
        $pdf->Image('../img/logo/logo-trans-bg.png', 20, 20, 20, 20);

        // name
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','I',12);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['name']) / 2), 32, $row['name']);

        // price
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
        $price1 = "£".$row['t1_price'];
        $pdf->Text(175 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($price1) / 2), 32, $price1);

        // date
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',12);
        $pdf->Text(155 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($date) / 2), 105, $date);

        // web address
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','BI',12);
        $pdf->Text(40 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth('dwhsociety.co.uk') / 2), 105, 'dwhsociety.co.uk');

        // concert title
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['title']) / 2), 60, $row['title']);

        // Adult
        if($row['type_1'] != '0'){
            $adult = "1 ticket ".$row['t1_label'];
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($adult) / 2), 67, $adult);
        }
    
        // venue
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['venue']) / 2), 77, $row['venue']);
    }

This of course creates a new page on every loop, which I don't want.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Obviously you'll need to adjust how you use $pdf->AddPage();. so it's not just there automatically at the start of each loop iteration. But you'll need to work out how many of your tickets are going to fit on a page, and then use some logic to only add a page when you've counted X number of tickets have been added. A simple counter variable would suffice for that. We can't tell you how many are going to fit on whatever page size you're aiming for.

It looks like every piece of PDF content you are creating there, gets written / placed at a specific pixel position (or whatever the actual coordinate system unit is.) So not only would you need to call AddPage only when necessary, but also modify the Y coordinate in all those places accordingly. (Basically, you'd want to add (height of a ticket + plus desired gap) * (number of the ticket on the current page - 1).)

Thank you both for your comments. However unless you are very familiar with how fpdf works, both are not the answer.
Fpdf automatically goes to a new page when the end of page is reached (or that is what the documentation says). But moving the $pdf->AddPage() outside the loop does not help this.
Adding a gap is also a problem.
But thanks anyway.

But moving the $pdf->AddPage() outside the loop does not help...nobody suggested doing that

@ADyson So sorry, didn't read your comment properly! In any case, I have nearly found the solution and will post the full code soon.

So, I have answered my own question.
As you probably can see from my original code, the tickets are printed from a database.
There are 3 types of tickets (adult, child and complimentary).
$gap = 150;

//--// type_1 tickets //--//
$type1_pages = $row['type_1']/2;
if(floor($type1_pages) == $type1_pages){
  $type1_whole = floor($type1_pages);
}else{
  $type1_whole = floor($type1_pages)+1;
}
$type1_fraction = $type1_whole - $type1_pages;

if($type1_pages != 0){
    for($i = 0; $i < $type1_whole; $i++){
    
        $pdf->AddPage();
    
        //--// Ticket 1 //--//
        // background
        $pdf->SetAlpha($alpha);
        $pdf->Image('../img/banners/'.$row['banner'], 10, 10, 0, 107);
        $pdf->SetXY(10,10);
        $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
        $pdf->Cell(0,107,'',1,1, 'C');

        // logo
        $pdf->Image('../img/logo/logo-trans-bg.png', 20, 20, 20, 20);

        // name
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','I',12);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['name']) / 2), 32, $row['name']);

        // price
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
        $price1 = "£".$row['t1_price'];
        $pdf->Text(180 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($price1) / 2), 32, $price1);

        // date
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',12);
        $pdf->Text(162 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($date) / 2), 105, $date);

        // web address
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','BI',12);
        $pdf->Text(40 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth('dwhsociety.co.uk') / 2), 105, 'dwhsociety.co.uk');

        // concert title
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['title']) / 2), 60, $row['title']);

        // Adult
        if($row['type_1'] != '0'){
            $adult = "1 ticket ".$row['t1_label'];
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($adult) / 2), 67, $adult);
        }

        // venue
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['venue']) / 2), 77, $row['venue']);
    
        //--// Ticket 2 //--//
        if(($type1_fraction == '0') || ($type1_whole-1 > $i)){
    
            // background
            $pdf->SetAlpha($alpha);
            $pdf->Image('../img/banners/'.$row['banner'], 10, 10+$gap, 0, 107);
            $pdf->SetXY(10,10+$gap);
            $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
            $pdf->Cell(0,107,'',1,1, 'C');

            // logo
            $pdf->Image('../img/logo/logo-trans-bg.png', 20, 20+$gap, 20, 20);

            // name
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','I',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['name']) / 2), 32+$gap, $row['name']);

            // price
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $price1 = "£".$row['t1_price'];
            $pdf->Text(180 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($price1) / 2), 32+$gap, $price1);

            // date
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',12);
            $pdf->Text(162 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($date) / 2), 105+$gap, $date);

            // web address
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','BI',12);
            $pdf->Text(40 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth('dwhsociety.co.uk') / 2), 105+$gap, 'dwhsociety.co.uk');

            // concert title
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['title']) / 2), 60+$gap, $row['title']);

            // Adult
            if($row['type_1'] != '0'){
                $adult = "1 ticket ".$row['t1_label'];
                $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
                $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($adult) / 2), 67+$gap, $adult);
            }

            // venue
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['venue']) / 2), 77+$gap, $row['venue']);
        }
    }
}

//--// type_2 tickets //--//
$type2_pages = $row['type_2']/2;
if(floor($type2_pages) == $type2_pages){
  $type2_whole = floor($type2_pages);
}else{
  $type2_whole = floor($type2_pages)+1;
}
$type2_fraction = $type2_whole - $type2_pages;

if($type2_pages != 0){
    for($i = 0; $i < $type2_whole; $i++){
    
        $pdf->AddPage();
    
        //--// Ticket 1 //--//
        // background
        $pdf->SetAlpha($alpha);
        $pdf->Image('../img/banners/'.$row['banner'], 10, 10, 0, 107);
        $pdf->SetXY(10,10);
        $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
        $pdf->Cell(0,107,'',1,1, 'C');

        // logo
        $pdf->Image('../img/logo/logo-trans-bg.png', 20, 20, 20, 20);

        // name
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','I',12);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['name']) / 2), 32, $row['name']);

        // price
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
        $price1 = "£".$row['t2_price'];
        $pdf->Text(180 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($price1) / 2), 32, $price1);

        // date
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',12);
        $pdf->Text(162 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($date) / 2), 105, $date);

        // web address
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','BI',12);
        $pdf->Text(40 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth('dwhsociety.co.uk') / 2), 105, 'dwhsociety.co.uk');

        // concert title
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['title']) / 2), 60, $row['title']);

        // Adult
        if($row['type_2'] != '0'){
            $adult = "1 ticket ".$row['t2_label'];
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($adult) / 2), 67, $adult);
        }

        // venue
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['venue']) / 2), 77, $row['venue']);
    
        //--// Ticket 2 //--//
        if(($type2_fraction == '0') || ($type2_whole-1 > $i)){
    
            // background
            $pdf->SetAlpha($alpha);
            $pdf->Image('../img/banners/'.$row['banner'], 10, 10+$gap, 0, 107);
            $pdf->SetXY(10,10+$gap);
            $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
            $pdf->Cell(0,107,'',1,1, 'C');

            // logo
            $pdf->Image('../img/logo/logo-trans-bg.png', 20, 20+$gap, 20, 20);

            // name
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','I',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['name']) / 2), 32+$gap, $row['name']);

            // price
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $price1 = "£".$row['t2_price'];
            $pdf->Text(180 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($price1) / 2), 32+$gap, $price1);

            // date
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',12);
            $pdf->Text(162 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($date) / 2), 105+$gap, $date);

            // web address
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','BI',12);
            $pdf->Text(40 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth('dwhsociety.co.uk') / 2), 105+$gap, 'dwhsociety.co.uk');

            // concert title
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['title']) / 2), 60+$gap, $row['title']);

            // Adult
            if($row['type_2'] != '0'){
                $adult = "1 ticket ".$row['t2_label'];
                $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
                $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($adult) / 2), 67+$gap, $adult);
            }

            // venue
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['venue']) / 2), 77+$gap, $row['venue']);
        }
    }
}

//--// type_3 tickets //--//
$type3_pages = $row['type_3']/2;
if(floor($type3_pages) == $type3_pages){
  $type3_whole = floor($type3_pages);
}else{
  $type3_whole = floor($type3_pages)+1;
}
$type3_fraction = $type3_whole - $type3_pages;

if($type3_pages != 0){
    for($i = 0; $i < $type3_whole; $i++){
    
        $pdf->AddPage();
    
        //--// Ticket 1 //--//
        // background
        $pdf->SetAlpha($alpha);
        $pdf->Image('../img/banners/'.$row['banner'], 10, 10, 0, 107);
        $pdf->SetXY(10,10);
        $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
        $pdf->Cell(0,107,'',1,1, 'C');

        // logo
        $pdf->Image('../img/logo/logo-trans-bg.png', 20, 20, 20, 20);

        // name
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','I',12);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['name']) / 2), 32, $row['name']);

        // price
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
        $price1 = "£".$row['t3_price'];
        $pdf->Text(180 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($price1) / 2), 32, $price1);

        // date
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',12);
        $pdf->Text(162 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($date) / 2), 105, $date);

        // web address
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','BI',12);
        $pdf->Text(40 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth('dwhsociety.co.uk') / 2), 105, 'dwhsociety.co.uk');

        // concert title
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['title']) / 2), 60, $row['title']);

        // Adult
        if($row['type_3'] != '0'){
            $adult = "1 ticket ".$row['t3_label'];
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($adult) / 2), 67, $adult);
        }

        // venue
        $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
        $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['venue']) / 2), 77, $row['venue']);
    
        //--// Ticket 2 //--//
        if(($type3_fraction == '0') || ($type3_whole-1 > $i)){
    
            // background
            $pdf->SetAlpha($alpha);
            $pdf->Image('../img/banners/'.$row['banner'], 10, 10+$gap, 0, 107);
            $pdf->SetXY(10,10+$gap);
            $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
            $pdf->Cell(0,107,'',1,1, 'C');

            // logo
            $pdf->Image('../img/logo/logo-trans-bg.png', 20, 20+$gap, 20, 20);

            // name
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','I',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['name']) / 2), 32+$gap, $row['name']);

            // price
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $price1 = "£".$row['t3_price'];
            $pdf->Text(180 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($price1) / 2), 32+$gap, $price1);

            // date
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',12);
            $pdf->Text(162 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($date) / 2), 105+$gap, $date);

            // web address
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','BI',12);
            $pdf->Text(40 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth('dwhsociety.co.uk') / 2), 105+$gap, 'dwhsociety.co.uk');

            // concert title
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['title']) / 2), 60+$gap, $row['title']);

            // Adult
            if($row['type_3'] != '0'){
                $adult = "1 ticket ".$row['t3_label'];
                $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
                $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($adult) / 2), 67+$gap, $adult);
            }

            // venue
            $pdf->SetFont('Courier','',12);
            $pdf->Text(105 - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($row['venue']) / 2), 77+$gap, $row['venue']);
        }
    }
}

// attachment name
$filename = "tickets.pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdf->Output();

I am sure the code could be written much better, but my brain is fried.
Hope this is of help to someone.
